# Show tablix total outside of table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a weekly report which totals anywhere from 200 - 1000 rows of data.  For my accounting people, the total is the only value of import as they simply use it for accrual purposes.  I would like to either have the total appear at the top of the report or in a separate text box indicating this is the total for the report.  Does anyone have a good idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to get the result of some aggregate function on a tablix shown in a textbox outside the tablix.

That can be achieved by placing a textbox anywhere on the report, and in the expression for that textbox add a reference to the dataset you need to aggregate, e.g.:

```
=Sum(Fields!SomeValue.Value, "myDataSet")
```

Where `SomeValue` is the name of the field you need to aggregate, and `myDataSet` is the name of the DataSet that fieldis in.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered by the other answer. Just as an alternative, you could try one more thing.

On the "details" row group(which appears by default), right click and choose "Add Total".

[image]

This will appear in a separate text box outside the report.